# ViewModel properties for properties of nested classes inside the model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, nested-class

I have an application following the MVVM pattern, that has to serialize XML files. As some of the XML attributes are nested, I've created nested classes inside my Model, like this:

```cs
public class OPER_FILE
{
    public UNB unb { get; set; }
    public OPER oper { get; set; }    //nested class, level 1

    public OPER_FILE()
    {
        unb = new UNB();
        oper = new OPER();
    }
}

public class OPER
{
    public UNH unh { get; set; }    //these are all nested classes, level 2
    public UVT uvt { get; set; }
    public VIN vin { get; set; }

    public OPER()
    {
        unh = new UNH();
        uvt = new UVT();
    }
}

#region "nested classes"
public class UNB
{
    public string unb { get; set; }
    public string unb_2 { get; set; }
}

public class UNH
{
    public string unh { get; set; }
    public string unh_2 { get; set; }
}

public class UVT
{
    public string uvt { get; set; }
    public string uvt_1 { get; set; }
    public string uvt_2 { get; set; }
}

public class VIN 
{
    public string vin { get; set; }
    public string vin_1 { get; set; }
    public string vin_2 { get; set; }
    public string vin_3 { get; set; }
    public string vin_4 { get; set; }
}
#endregion
```

The attributes of the nested classes are all strings, because this simplifies the XML serialization for now (I'm still in the conception phase).

In my corresponding ViewModel, I've simply created a property for the nested class inside the model, so I can access all of the nested properties with just referring to this nested class from the ViewModel.

```cs
public class OPERViewModel : IViewModelBase
{
    private OPER_FILE Model;

    public UNB unb 
    { 
        get
        { return Model.unb;}
        set
        { Model.unb = value; }
    }

    public OPER oper
    {
        get
        { return Model.oper; }    //this is the tricky part, by now I'm just referring to the nested class as a property of the model
        set
        { Model.oper = value; }
    }

    public OPERViewModel()
    { Model = new OPER_FILE(); }
}
```

The question is, however, that I want to display some of the properties not as strings but as boolean values using checkboxes on the UI.

Saying I want to display `Model.oper.vin.vin_1` as boolean (where the ViewModel should manage the conversion from `string` to `bool` in the getter of its own property reflection of `Model.oper.vin.vin_1`), how would I do that?

Would I *really* have to implement every nested property from a nested class as an own property of the ViewModel (like stated below) to gain control over the way it will be returned to the UI?

```cs
//ViewModel-implementation with type-conversion of a property from a nested class of the model
//this would get bind to the UI instead of Model.oper.vin.vin_1
public bool vin_1    
{
    get
    {
        if (Model.oper.vin.vin_1 == "1")
        { return true; }
        else
        { return false; }
    }
    set
    {
        if (value)
        { Model.oper.vin.vin_1 = "1"; }
        else
        { Model.oper.vin.vin_1 = "0"; }
    }
}
```

I hope there is a better solution out there...

---

**Edit:**

What I forgot to mention before, there're not only `string`s that have to be displayed as `boolean`s, also `DateTime`-values that should be displayed as a `DatePicker`-control, integer-values that I would like to have as `NumberPicker`s and so on.

The xml-file, on the other hand, will be consumed by an interface with some pretty fixed regulations that i need to match, such a dynamically leading zeros on both `integer`- and `float`-values, special date formats and commas instead of dots as decimal separators. So sticking with the `string`-values inside the object to serialize is a good way of maintaining control over how the values would get actually parsed inside the xml-file.

I'll try and experiment with some different converters, as @BrandlyDOTNet reommended, but are still curious about how this could be solved in another way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a *different* solution out there, namely that you can use a **converter** to define the translation between your strings and a bool.

Something like:

```
public class StringToBoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
   public object Convert(...)
   {
       return value.ToString() != "0";
   }

   public object ConvertBack(...)
   {
       bool boolVal = (bool)value;
       return boolVal ? "1" : "0";
   }
}
```

Usage:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked={Binding SomeProp, Converter={StaticResource StringToBoolConverter}"/>
```

But to answer your deeper question, no, the framework will not just convert the string "1" into a bool. Moreover, you can strongly type your object that is being serialized, so *none of this is actually necessary*.

Comment: By *strongly typing* you mean changing all those `string`s to actual useful datatypes, better matching their values, I guess. I could and strongly awaiting to have to as the project progresses. But I'm bound to the special needs of an interface that is meant to consume the xml-file and has some strictly fixed format-regulations that I have to match. As rapid app development is the order of the day, I was hoping I could stick with the string variables in by now and find something to reduce the amount of code to write. 

And so I did, thanks to you, I'll take a look at this `Converter`-thing.